# Как правильнее описать объект в JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Как мне правильно описать данную функцию?

```js
/**
 * Allows to search posts on user or community walls.
 * @param {Object} params
 * @property {string} params.domain user or community screen name
 * @property {number} params.owner_id user or community id
 * @property {string} params.querry search query string
 * @property {number} [params.count=1] 1 – returns only page owner's posts (1 default, either 1 or 0)
 * @property {number} [params.ownersOnly=1] count of posts to return (1 default, either 1 or 0)
 * @property {number} [params.offset=0] results offset (0 default)
 * @property {number} [params.extended] show extended post info (either 1 or 0)
 * @property {string} [params.fields] list of comma-separated words
 * @returns {Promise} JSON Response
 */
async search(params)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

**На данный момент вот так показывается подсказка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Если вместо @property использовать @params, то выглядит куда лучше, но нет описания и не показывается значение по умолчанию (должно ли вообще?):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Используемый редактор - VSCode.**

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте можете указать @type {Object} params

Подробнее есть описание в этом посте [How to describe “object” arguments in jsdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460604/how-to-describe-object-arguments-in-jsdoc)